# Is it known whether the MD5 algorithm is surjective?

Tags: reference-request, hash

Does MD5 map to all possible 128 bit numbers? To put it another way:
For every 128 bit number `y`, does there exist at least one `x` for which `md5(x) = y`?

The answer probably is yes, for arbitrary `x`, and probably no proof exists. However, feel free to prove me wrong :)

But what if I impose some kind of limit on `x`, e.g. `x <= x_max`? Of course, for very small `x_max` the answer is no. But what is the minimum value of `x_max` for which the answer likely becomes yes? Or the maximum value for which the answer can be shown to be no?

I'm not really interested in the exact value for `x_max`, rather in the approximate order of magnitude.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658601/do-cryptographic-hash-functions-reach-each-possible-value-e-g-are-they-surject. In particular, the part in the accepted answer that talks about the "random oracle." It seems clear that the only way to prove surjectivity of a hash function is by exhaustive search.

Comment: @jim-mischel: I did see that, and the second comment to that answer claims that its main argument is wrong. I can't verify that, or else I hadn't asked that question here. The question/answer also is five years old and doesn't mention MD5, so I thought I might try to get a more specific response :)

Comment: I wonder if [cs.SE] was the best migration target. [security.SE], [cryptography.SE] (because of the use of MD5 lies there) or even [math.SE] (because you ask about mathematical properties of a function) may have been better.

Answer (score 3):

> **Q:** Does MD5 map to all possible 128 bit numbers?

Taking into account the facts that MD5 accepts input of the arbitrary length, the output is "only" 128 bits, and the [algorithm itself](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/MD5/Implementation#Java) which behaves similarly to random functions, I would expect that the all outputs are possible. However, without any strong mathematical evidence, this is merely a speculation, or in the best case, the hunch.

> **Q:** The answer probably is yes, for arbitrary x, and probably no proof exists.

Exactly, there is no proof (currently). Proving that MD5 is surjective would require either one of these:

- Brute force check - taking into account coupon's collector problem, it takes something like 10^40 inputs to hit all 128-bit outputs. Assuming again that MD5 behaves similarly to random function, that should be enough to verify **in the case that MD5 is surjective**.
- Concrete mathematical proof - eventual proof of surjectivity should be able for arbitrary 128-bit number y prove that there exists some input x such that MD5(x) = y. That should require deep mathematical analysis of MD5 function and it would probably shed some light on reversing this hash function. Even though MD5 is far from desirable hash function, it is still not known how to predict the input based on the given output.

Comment: "the existence of [a proof] would probably require breaking the hash function" -- how so? Popular PRNGs are surjective and you don't need to "break" them in order to show that. (However can you break a hash function, anyway?)

Comment: @DavidRicherby You are aware that MD5 is far from this pathological example that you provided. More convincing example would be f(x)=2x, which at least takes x into account :) However, I got your point so I edited my answer. And I am curious, how would you represent 1000 with nine bits?

Comment: @Raphael - nice example with PRNGs, thanks.

Comment: "That should require deep mathematical analysis of MD5 function and it would probably shed some light on reversing this hash function." -- I still don't follow this train of thought. The simple hash function $x \mod n$ for $x$ a number encoding of your data is trivially surjective, assuming $x$ does not have a very weird domain. I don't see how this knowledge makes is worse as a hash function. (Security by obscurity is no security at all!)

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Nine bits? It's not computer science if there aren't off-by-one errors. \*cough\*

Comment: @Raphael I am not proponent of security through obscurity! Knowledge of the algorithms for calculating popular hash functions or PKI encryption/decryption doesn't help you to get the original message without some additional information (that would help to prove surjectivity as well, IMHO). Regarding your example, if `n` is small, that is a bad hash function because buckets become large. Otherwise, for sufficiently large `n`, if you use this function for hashing passwords (common usage of e.g. MD5), brute-force attack is much easier - check only those numbers that give specific residue mod `n`.

Comment: Why is the answer probably yes? It could as well be probably no. MD5 does a lot of bit shifting, and rotating and xoring. Bits get lost. It's a 50/50 chance. It could be surjective, or maybe not.

Comment: A proof that it's not surjective would be very easy - is there any bit that isn't possible to set. For example if for all inputs we can never get one of the bits set (because of all bit xoring and rotating and shifting etc), then it's not surjective as that one bit is never set.

Comment: @bodacydo I am not saying that the answer is probably yes, I was citing the author of the question.
How can you prove that there is a bit that isn't possible to set, or something similar? One thing is to believe that some statement is valid, completely other is to actually prove it. That's why in math you have *conjectures*.